# How can I print the command-line run arguments of a running jar file?

Tags: java

So I have a program that’s already running, and I want to know what command-line arguments are being used to run the jar. I can see the arguments passed to the jar with the java attach library, but I want to know what class path and other run arguments are being used. Is there any way of printing this to the terminal in any way? Java code or otherwise.

Note: I am NOT looking for how to run a jar with classpath arguments, that’s all I’ve been able to find on google

Messed around with the VirtualMachine and VirtualMachineDescriptor classes, did some googling, and didn’t find anything other than looping through the string array parameter in the entry point method, which is not at all what I’m looking for.

Comment: What are you trying to do? When you start a process, you know what parameters you pass it. You can log these from your startup script.

Comment: I'm debugging a program that I did not write. It uses Java 19, and people these days all seem to just have Java 8 downloaded, so it uses a launcher to download an openjdk jvm and run the program. The launcher is written in a language that compiles to machine code, and I don't have the knowledge to go through the assembly and figure out the individual command-line arguments being used.

Comment: Does `ps -w` show you what you need?

Comment: Or on windows maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Running this on a mac does not seem to give any information relating to Java whatsoever, I only see xcode programms running with ps -w

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't compiled with `native-image`? Why do you think it's a running jar?

Comment: Procmon was perfect and easy to use, thank you, it worked!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've never worked with native images in Java, but I know the jar file location and it looks like authentic java bytecode to me, not some fancy way of compiling it to machine code or something

Comment: you might need `ps -axw`

Comment: What is the difference between 'I can see the arguments passed to the jar' and 'I want to know what class path and other run arguments are being used'? Please explain.

Comment: Task Manager -> Details -> Rightclick the column header -> Select columns -> Command Line.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you tgdavies, procmon learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon worked perfectly, was intuitive, and easy to use